# Different Apps within the same app

Tags: android, ios, google-apps

i developed an app that contains a lot of activities and different application within the same app and they are all interconnected by sending different intents within it to function the whole app, however they still do different things and i can elimante one without hurting the other and causing the whole app to crash. so if i want i can divide them to be stand alone apps.

My question is this:

Can i have one app that download the basic activities and if a person want a specific activity they can download it (Eg: you download a game and that game includes a different set of levels that can be downloaded by pressing a button hence downloads that particular set of levels.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me if I misunderstood you, but are you talking about creating one big app that consists of many smaller apps, but rather than being all bundled in the beginning, a user can download each one as a module?

If it's this, it's not impossible, but not possible in the sense that I think you're hoping for.

Your one big app will still need all the necessary code and xml files because these need to exist when compiling. But what you can do, which is similar to what games do is to offer downloadable content that isn't code. Essentially, these are resources such as media files, text, or other data of the like.

Those data can be downloaded separately without affecting your app and it helps reduce the size of your app. However, the actual functionality of each individual app will still need to be within your app, but hidden until it's downloaded.

Typically, it's more common to just bundle it all together such as a Measurements app, or to have them as individual standalone apps such as Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides.

Comment: Well thanks for answering kind of a vague question. and you understood correctly, but you missed my point. is it possible to not have to bundle all in the beginning? as my app uses cloud so the media files are no problem but rather the java, kotlin, and XML files. i was wondering if it possible to download those resources later.

Comment: @KaramJaber It would be at the least extremely difficult to do that, and risks getting you kicked from the play store because they can't analyze all of your code for malware.  Having it in separate apps and check if its downloaded and redirecting to the play store if not is a lot easier.

Comment: @KaramJaber Nope, those files can't be downloaded later.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically describing how a browser/website works.

If you really wanted to wrap this up as a mobile app, you could use webviews.